# Restricting the evaluation of variables

Tags: replacement, variable, c++

Hopefully you understand my question.
I
m calculating inverse kinematics of a robot and each subsequent value is dependant on the one before. For simple porting into c++ I would like something like this to be possible:

```
A = x^2   
B = A^2
```

> ```
> x^2
> x^4
> ```

But I want

> ```
> x^2
> A^2
> ```

Is this possible in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Use `HoldForm` on the second assignment. Or you can use it on both and get the expanded expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Use SetDelayed (`:=`)

```
a = x^2;
b := a^2
?b
```

> b:=a^2

As you can see, `b` is still `a^2`.

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html